# Is it possible to have the lasso selection button outside of the modebar and inside a html button?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I want to have the lasso selection button in a more prominant position and to be always visible inside its own html tag rather than only appearing when the use hovers over the plot area.

I'm unable to figure out how to use the answer suggested in [this post](https://community.plotly.com/t/any-way-to-choose-the-lasso-select-tool-programatically-with-api/7834) using Plotly Dash.

Mant thanks.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question?

Comment: I can't remember sorry but I probably because I was worried it was too low quality a question. If you had a comment I'm very sorry!

Comment: No problem :). I asked because I thought it was a valuable question.